Install4j PKCS11 library for macOS
I have purchased an EV code signing certificate to sign the windows installer created with Install4j. The certificate is installed on a hardware module. Im running Install4j 10 on macOS Sonoma and need to specify the PKCS #11 Library.
Where do I get that library from? Where is it located?

You have to ask the vendor who provided the HSM, they will be able to provide the correct driver library
